# How can you improve an (approved) edit suggestion?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

If you take a look at this screenshot (of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41509641/i-cant-figure-out-what-is-wrong-with-this-code)), it shows that Joel has managed to improve 12 edit suggestions, and I have done zero.

[image: Edit suggestions]

Thing is, I have tried many times to find out how, but the best I have managed so far is click the Edit button on the question itself and paste line by line the edit suggestions, and then improve. Which makes the edit mine, will not count towards "improved edit suggestions" (whatever that is), but more importantly and annoyingly, this is way too much work.

TL;DR: how do you improve on an edit suggestion, how does Joel do this?

*PS: I am fully aware that in a few minutes I will likely feel very stupid for not finding that one button that everybody knows of, maybe right in the middle of that popup, I just honestly don't see it.* — yep, see answer ;).

Comment: In the suggested edit review queue, there should be an Improve Edit button next to the Approve button...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan, so.... how do I get there from the popup? Or is the only route to go to the queue, locate this specific one and then improve it there?

Comment: No, the button is in the popup as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you decide you want to *im*prove, rather than just *ap*prove the edit, you need to decide upfront. Once you click the <kbd>Approve</kbd> button, there's no going back.

[image]

or, from the post itself:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean, same popup?

Comment: The first one isn't a popup, though. The content is indeed the same, but that might not be obvious.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean you see different things than I do? I didn't cut my popup short from the top, but I don't see what you are seeing.

Comment: @Abel could you go [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30913073/4751173) and post a screenshot of what you see when you click the `edit(1)` link?

Comment: Aaaaah, wait (facepalm), my process was **Approve >> Improve** (one after the other), but this doesn't work, it is only either **Approve** or **Improve (approve implied)**.

Comment: So, yes, I see the same as you in that last link. I was simply confused by being able to click on it again and not being able to edit it. And frustrated that, even if I go to edit history, I would still see the old version. So, after clicking `Approve`, the only way to `Improve` is to wait.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: I've updated my question's title to reflect this. So basically the answer is now "you can't", or "think before you click _Approve_".

Comment: Technically, it's still possible to edit; I think you can rollback to an earlier revision (this invalidates the edit review) and continue editing from there. However, this would deny the editor his +2 reputation, and more important, this is sort of misusing the tools.